# Count and display the most to less count in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
SELECT t1.CompanyName, COUNT(*) AS TotalOrder
FROM [table1] t1 
INNER JOIN [table2] t2 ON t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID
 GROUP BY t1.CompanyID
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I have the above code already just that wish to display the most count To the top and less count at the bottom in the gridview how can I do this?

Comment: so you just want the row number in descending order?

Comment: Did you checked binding the same result? You already sorted the result according to count and it should give you proper order in grid also.

Comment: How can I checked the binding?

Answer (score 2):

Try This query.

```
SELECT t1.CompanyName, COUNT(t2.CompanyID) AS TotalOrder
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
     ON t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID
GROUP BY t1.CompanyName
ORDER BY TotalOrder DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand your question is you want the Company Names listed with row number in descending order. if so try this

```
SELECT t1.CompanyName, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by CompanyName) AS TotalOrder
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID order by CompanyName desc
```